# Rx Swift discards .do(onNext: {}) How do I make it trigger?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, observable, rx-swift

I'm trying to convert my `firebase` project to work with `rx swift` but the `.do(onNext:{})` is discarded while the `onCompleted` trigger in the `subscription`.

I made an `observable` function of the `firebase` code:

```
func fetchFireBaseData() -> Observable<[Recipe]> {
    return Observable.create({ [weak self] observer -> Disposable in
        guard let self = self else { return Disposables.create() }
        
        self.databaseRef.child(self.recipeType.description).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let data = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            for item in data {
                guard let thisItem = item.value as? NSDictionary else { return }
                   
                let tempRecipe = Recipe()
                tempRecipe.fbKey = item.key
                tempRecipe.recipeImageObject = (thisItem["recipeImageFirebase"] as? String) ?? ""
                tempRecipe.recipeHeaderObject = (thisItem["recipeHeaderFirebase"] as? String) ?? ""
                tempRecipe.recipeTextObject = (thisItem["recipeIngredientsTextFirebase"] as? String) ?? ""
                   
                    self.recipeArray.append(tempRecipe)

                    }
                    observer.onNext(self.recipeArray)

            })
            observer.onCompleted()
            return Disposables.create()
        })
```

and from the part that call the function:

```
func reloadContent() -> Observable<[Recipe]> {
    guard let fbDataHandler = fbDataHandler else { return Observable.just([]) }
    return fbDataHandler.fetchFireBaseData().do(onNext: { [weak self] value in
            print("WHY ISNT THIS BEING CALLED?")
            self?.content.accept(value.compactMap { RecipesCollectionViewCellViewModel(recipes: $0) })   
        })
```

The `.do(onNext:` is ignored, and I don't understand why. The completion work though:

```
viewModel?.reloadContent().subscribe(onCompleted: {
    print("THIS IS CALLED")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Any idea why it won't work? I read here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1212 that

```
a.do(onNext: {
  print($0) // not called 
}) <-- result is observable sequence that is discarded
```

But I'm not really sure what that means or how to fix it.

***EDIT***
Ok, so this possible to fix with a completion handler, BUT the whole idea with rx is to do stuff like this without completion handlers no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are emitting the `onCompleted()` immediately after calling `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` without giving the closure a chance to get called. The solution is to call the `onCompleted()` inside the closure, after the `onNext(_:)`.

There are a number of other problems as well. If `self` is null, this Observable will never emit anything, no next event nor any error or completed event. The fact that self is being referenced at all in the create closure is a poor practice. Define `recipeArray` inside the create closure instead.

Also pass `databaseRef` as a parameter to the function, either by making this a higher order function or by making the function and extension of the class that `databaseRef` is an instance of.

Also, `Recipe` should not be a class. It should be a struct because it's a value object.

Something like this:

```
extension Reactive where Base: DatabaseRef {
    func fetchFireBaseData(recipeType: RecipeType) -> Observable<[Recipe]> {
        Observable.create { observer in
            base.child(recipeType.description)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    guard let data = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                        observer.onError(DBError.noDataSnapshots)
                        return
                    }
                    let recipeArray = data.compactMap { (item) -> Recipe? in
                        guard let thisItem = item.value as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
                        return Recipe(
                            fbKey: item.key,
                            recipeImageObject: (thisItem["recipeImageFirebase"] as? String) ?? "",
                            recipeHeaderObject: (thisItem["recipeHeaderFirebase"] as? String) ?? "",
                            recipeTextObject: (thisItem["recipeIngredientsTextFirebase"] as? String) ?? ""
                        )
                    }
                    observer.onNext(recipeArray)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                })
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, that makes so much sense! Thanks for helping me out and thanks for all the other pointers. It works now - awesome :)